# Parse JSON API response on date

Tags: php, json

So I'm having some issues formatting my JSON Date response and I wanted to see if someone could help me.

- Here is the JSON API Response that I'm getting: `"ArriveOnLocal": "/Date(1610416800000)/",`
- This can be accessed using: `$item->ArriveOnLocal`.

**What I've tried w/ no output on screen luck**:

```
<?php DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $item->ArriveOnLocal); ?>  
<?= date('m/d/Y', $item->ArriveOnLocal); ?>
```

I'd like to get a return response such as `01/12/2021`.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you define `$item`? Where is that code?

Comment: `createFromFormat` expects you to tell it the format you are creating the data object **from**!

Comment: `w/ no output on screen luck` .... nothing in your code question displays anything on screen, except maybe errors

Comment: `var_dump($item->ArriveOnLocal)` outputs the following: `string(21) "/Date(1610416800000)/"`

Comment: Wasnt what I asked. I asked to show the code where `$item` is defined